# How to see Caffe perdiction label of the test set?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

It's already asked question in [github](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/391) but since no specific answer been issued and some changes been made to Caffe framework and other things that i am going to explain, i thought it is better to ask it again.

When Caffe framework learning/testing phase happen, in each iteration, it give us an Loss and Accuracy values, but Accuracy is not a good measurement parameter, so i need to see each prediction on test images, **one by one** to calculate other measurement parameters like Precision and maybe recall.

If i run :

```
import caffe

net = caffe.Net('/path/to/model_def.prototxt', '/path/to/model/weights')
out = net.forward()
```

It will give us prediction of first batch images in `out['prob']`, and i don't want prediction for batch of images, How can i get theme one by one?

Comment: Simply use a batch of size one? Or just analyze a batch of images? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro , you can't change batch size in deploy prototxt, and you can not change batch size to 1 in main prototxt, it will ruin your learning phase.

Answer (score 2):

The results will be stored in the `out['prob'].data` array. The first dimension of the array corresponds to the batch. So, to view the results of the `i`th image, check the values in `out['prob'].data[i]`.

Assuming this is classification, where each image has a value assigned for every class, the output corresponding to the `i`th image for the `j`th class can be found at `out['prob'].data[i][j]`.

Comment: Thank you. good idea. but is Caffe read my csv of image file sequentially ? (i did not create lmdb database)

Comment: @comeymacdonald How are you providing the input?

Comment: I've made CSV file of ([image/address] [label]) and gave it address to caffe in data layer.

Comment: @comeymacdonald I am not sure of the answer to that, sorry. My guess is it should be in order.

Comment: sorry , I did that, net.blobs['prob'].data , actually gave me a 2x1 matrix and out['prob'].data gave me empty matrix , so which image is that ? what happened to batch images? do i have to run it 30,000 time to get theme all ?

Comment: And all probabilities are the same if i forward it iteratively.

Comment: @comeymacdonald sorry for the late response. I realized there's another mistake - `out = net.forward()` is not correct. You set the data, then do `net.forward()`, and `net.blobs['prob'].data` contains the array with the output. If your last layer is softmax, batch size is n, and number of classes is m, then it should be n x m.